# android internet connection error fails

Tags: java, android, web-applications, error-handling

Hi I try to show the user a costum file if the internet connection fails. In this case it works fine. If the internet connection works and `index.php` become loaded all works until then.

If I click on a button on `index.php` and the user become redirected to another page say we `login.php` the costum error file starts. Thats bad. How can the file myerrorpage.html only become showed when the internet connection fail and not the project file change?

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_localy);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Brower niceties -- pinch / zoom, follow links in place
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());     
    // Load google.com
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://192./loc/index.php");

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError%29),

> Report web resource loading error to the host application. These errors usually indicate inability to connect to the server. Note that unlike the deprecated version of the callback, **the new version will be called for any resource (iframe, image, etc), not just for the main page**. Thus, it is recommended to perform minimum required work in this callback.

This method is not the best place to check for Internet Connectivity Issues. You can manually check for Internet Connectivity and Load the error page.